# SQL with many results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL that brings back all the users of a system in a MySQL database with PHP and I need to get these users and move them to another system (don't worry about the fields, I already map them). The problem is that I have more than 67000 users in the database. Is there any way I can do that with PHP and get all the results at once?? Cause I tried and give me a error, not an error, but the PHP can't return all the results at once.

Comment: please post error message and code that executes query and fetches result.

Comment: please show us what you have tried and what the error message was

Comment: Have you properly set up the timeout and memory related variables?

Comment: It gives you an error but not an error? Maybe you should check your `memory_limit` in php.ini...

Comment: Another option is to migrate the data using MySQL only. If you don't need multiple re-calculations per field, [you could do an `INSERT INTO … SELECT FROM …`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have reached PHP's default memory limit.
You have (at least) 2 options:

1. fetch them all at once (like you do now), and increase the memory PHP may use in that script. You can find it under the name "memory_limit".
   https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php
   Take care you only do that for your current script, not systemwide by modifying php.ini.
2. Fetch your records in smaller batches, like 1000 per time. That way you won't hit your memory limit.

In both cases you might want to increase the time your script can run too. Have a look at max-execution-time.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: Thanks very much :) That's why I know that Stackoverflow is the best community of users that helps each other.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on top of your PHP script:
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

You can give the php script less that 512MB ofc

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit in SQL

limit 0, 1000

limit 10001, 2000

etc